# Proper Kentico object for non-user-editable block of static html/javascript

Tags: kentico

**The Situation:** I've got a mid-sized chunk of html/javascript that contains an authentication script/input (it's a text input, radio control, and a combo box and a few buttons).  What it is is less important than the concept that it's a mass of static client side code that the marketing department can pretty easily accidentally the whole thing.

**The Desire:** I want the users to be able to add it as a whole to a page, but not be able to modify it.  When something needs to change, I want to change it in one place and have it be changed on all the pages.

**What I've Tried:** Widget with a default text.  It works, but feels wrong. Users can edit it, and if they do when I fix it one place it doesn't propagate to all the instances.  I'm a bit of a Kentico noob, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Also note: I'm using portal engine if that makes a difference.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Using the latest (8.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget is the proper usage.  What you make your widget inherit from is the key in this case.  I'd suggest creating a new widget based on a static HTML webpart.  This way you can set the static HTML markup and hide the property from the content editor on the front end.  You can do this by going to the Properties tab of the widget and setting the visibility of the field on the form.  Don't delete the field, just hide it.  It should be a checkbox that says hide on public form or editing form.

** Edit **
As I read through my answer and comments, I realized I meant to say clone the static HTML webpart and set its default text to your javascript. Then create a widget based on that cloned webpart.  The text will reside in the web part and will allow you to update it in one place later, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I don't think this confirms to his requirement that you can update the text in one place and have it propagate to all the widgets since it's stored inside the page's content definition.

Answer (score 1):

I will not do it this way because you will be not able to make changes in the future. You can better create a new webpart this can be an empty webpart and then create a custom layout. In this layout you can put you're code.  In this way you can always change you're code in the future and then it will be changed on all the places where the widget is placed.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd create a new webpart?  It's static HTML.  So I'd use a static HTML webpart and create it as a widget with the markup already coded in it.  The content editor doesn't have to configure anything, just place the widget on the page.  Creating a new webpart adds complexity and additional code that isn't needed.

Comment: If you place the code in the property of the widget you cannot update the widget in the future, therefore the best solution is to use the web part layouts, this is code that is saved in the DB so it can be changed by only using Kentico without releasing files and when changed all widgets are updated. You can achieve this by creating an empty webpart, but if you don’t want the extra code you can also copy an simple exiting webpart as for example the static HTML code and then use another web part layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a new widget based on the Static HTML webpart (make the field read only or hide it as Brenden mentioned), but store the data in a new custom setting.

- no coding needed (only a macro to read the custom setting)
- able to edit the script on the fly on any instance in the settings module. If you have multiple of these settings you won't need to go through all kinds of widgets to adjust their default setting but find them on a central place.

Cheers!

David

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think it makes sense to create a custom web part to store all your code in it and use it that way. If you want to achieve it without creating a custom web part, you have to store the code in some non-web part and not widget specific object. I like the suggestion of creating a custom setting. You can then access this custom setting via a macro. This macro can be used as a default property of a newly created  web part (inherited e.g. from the static text web part, you'd use the text property). You may as well create a widget out of it. Another approach is to use Kentico localization keys as a workaround. you can create a key in the Localization application and access it again, via a macro, e.g. {?customkey.myhtml?}. The approach with a custom setting however sounds cleaner to me.

This syntax should be working to access a custom setting value via macro:

```
   {%Settings.CustomSettings.xxx%}
   {%Settings.CustomSettings["xxx"]%}
   {%Settings.CustomSettings.GetValue("xxx")%}
```